# Error while finding the time difference in SQL Sybase using DATEDIFF function

Tags: t-sql, sybase

[image]

I have the following query to find the difference between two dates in minutes.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'28.11.2019 09:23:41:202',GETDATE()) AS time_difference
```

But, I am getting the error

> Converting '28.11.2019 09:23:41:202 'to timestamp is not possible
>   SQLCODE = -157, ODBC 3 State = "07006"

The value '28.11.2019 09:23:41:202' is obtained by using GETDATE() function in a previous query.
What is wrong here? any help?

**UPDATE:**

The query works if the value '28.11.2019 09:23:41:202' is changed to "2019.11.28" format. As mentioned above,

The value "'28.11.2019 09:23:41:202'" is obtained from using the same function GETDATE() in a previous query.

Comment: Please try this `SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2019-11-27 08:55:12:564',GETDATE()) AS time_difference`

Comment: @jishansiddique thankyou jishan..This works!! But then, to get the value in YYYY-MM-DD format, I need to do some extra conversions right. Also, the date "27.11.2019 08:55:12:564" was obtained using the same GETDATE() function .

Comment: Your SQL client is formatting the getdate() somehow if you run this via isql you would get see similar to 'Nov 28 2019  6:58AM'. Using DD.MM.YYYY format is bad because depending on regional settings months and year can be reversed and you hit syntax issues. For example in the UK we use DD.MM.YYYY but in the US they assume MM.DD.YYYY.

Answer (score 2):

You need to utilise a standard date-time format, for it to work. For example, see following query:

```
select DateDiff(minute, '2019-11-28 08:12:34', GetDate()) as time_difference
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. I understood nwo that I have to use the format YYYY-MM-DD instead of DD-MM-YYYY. But, the value '27.11.2019 08:55:12:564' was obtained using teh GETDATA() function in a previous query. So, if I want to use it to find the differenec, then I have to do a conversion?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If this solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The date format YYYY-MM-DD is still a problem. The date time stamp which I can use is in the format as my question.

Comment: I think the problem might be the milli-seconds, there should be a full-stop separating it from the seconds, in your example you've got a colon. 

You have put '27.11.2019 08:55:12:564' as the date time format. It should be '27.11.2019 08:55:12.564'.

Comment: I tried..but it i snot the problem. The problem is with the date format. It works only if the dateformat is YYYY.MM.DD and not with DD.MM.YYYY

Comment: You mention a function. Where does this function get the value from? 

If it is from a another Datetime/DateTime2 field elsewhere in the database then, as long as it is of the same collation as the rest of the database, then it should bring it back in the correct format.

Comment: I am using the same GETDATE() function/query

Comment: I appreciate that. My question was where does the other date - the date you are comparing to GetDate() come from? Has that from a DateTime/DateTime2 field, or has it come from a varchar/nvarchar field?

Comment: May be my answer was confusing :/ In the query "SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '28-11-2019 08:12:34:534', GETDATE()) AS time_difference", the value - '28-11-2019 08:12:34:534' is obtained from a previous query "SELECT GETDATE()"

Comment: That's strange. I wouldn't have thought you would need to convert the date in that instance. However, to get it into the year-month-date format, you could use: convert(datetime, getdate(), 121) - where 121 is the code for that date format.

Comment: I tried that, its still returning in dd.mm.yyyy format. I don't understand why this s happening. I am in europe time zone, where the standard format is dd.mm.yyyy. Upon using the convert with the code '121', the format remains the same.

Comment: I've got to admit. I'm struggling with this one. If you do find the answer, please let me know.

Comment: what SQL client are you using it could well be that the client is the thing which is translating the getdate() to the problem format. Try with native isql from SAP and this shouldn't have that issue

Answer (score 0):

Example from [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,      '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
```